# Tree child can only have one of field tag,

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

Tree child can only have one of field tag,button, control, groupby, widget, header tag (not feild).

**Odoo Server Error**

```
Error while validating view near:

                            <tree>
                                <feild name="CustomerDetailIds">

                            </feild>

 1. Tree child can only have one of field, button, control, groupby, widget, header tag (not feild)
```

**Code XML:**

```
 <record id="view_tailor_detail_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">tailor detail form</field>
        <field name="model">tailor.data.detail</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form>
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="name"/>
                            <field name="Phone"/>
                        </group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="table_no"/>
                            <field name="Catagory"/>
                            <field name="costumer_detail_id"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                    <notebook>
                        <page string="Customer detail">
                            <tree>
                                <feild name="CustomerDetailIds">

                            </feild>

                            <feild name="C_ids">

                            </feild>
                            <feild name="details">

                            </feild>
                            </tree>


                        </page>
                    </notebook>
                </sheet>

            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

> But when I remove the tree tag it works fine but not find any output fields on UI side.

Comment: @marc_s Please don't edit code in questions to fix the errors that the question is asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use *tree* tag inside a *one2many* or *many2many* field.

In your case, you declared *tree* tag inside *page* tag. So Odoo can not find a valid field.

So removing the *tree* tag will work or use it inside *one2many* or *many2many* field.

For example:

```
<field name="one2many_field">
    <tree>
        <field name="x">
        <field name="y">
    </tree>
    <form>
        <group>
            <field name="x">
            <field name="y">
        </group>
    </tree>
</field>
```

Answer (score 1):

"feild" is incorrect, change it to "field"